# Pandas: how to check if column could be coerced into bool / SQL BIT?

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [None, None, True, True, False]})
```

`col1` could be coerced into a boolean column and inserted into a SQL table containing a `BIT` datatype.

But, how can I use pandas to check the column for whether or not such an operation is suitable/possible?

The following does not operate like I expect:

```
isinstance(df['col1'].dtype, bool)  # False
```

Here is a slightly more complicated attempt, looking only at the True and False values:

```
isinstance(df.loc[~df['col1'].isna()], bool)  # False
```

Another possible check that seems to work on simple cases:

```
True in df['col1'].to_numpy() or False in df['col1'].to_numpy()
```

Comment: try to coerce it and see if it fails would be the straightforward way

Comment: This does not work because I could end up trying that on string columns and it would coerce a string column without question.

Comment: ... yes, because they are *coercible*.  But if you want to exclude that, then check and make sure it is not `object` dtype

Comment: But my example is also identified as an `object` dtype, so they are equivalent to pandas from that perspective.

Comment: Well then you have to hand-write whatever logic you want to implement. Note, generally speaking, `object` dtypes are a bad sign, you shouldn't end up with a column like your example ideally. So, there probably isn't any neat and tidy solution.